# FOSUserBundle form looks like strange

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I have just configured and prepared the FOSUserBundle on my Symfony project. But when I try to show the register view looks like that:

> [image]

The register form (by default) should look like:

> [image: Blockquote]

All what I configured is on [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html), I don't know what happend.

This is the **RegistrationFormType.html.twig** from FOSUserBundle:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        ...

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('email', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType'), array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
                ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
                ->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
                    'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                ))
            ;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: you need to have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as @michal-g told, i had to uncomment that line. I did the overriding part before to find that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First  of all  you should  run translation component

in  config.yml 
uncomment line
`translator: { fallbacks: ["en"] }`

and (like was  said in comment)  read  about  overriding  views

Comment: That's it! It solved my problem. I uncommented that line and it worked. Thank you Michal.

Comment: Of course, I have just accepted it as solution, check it! ;-)